# Sitecore Analytics truncation

Tags: analytics, sitecore, truncate

We have implemented Sitecore for our future site. We are going live soon with our corporate site. We had some testing done on this site to make sure everything was working right. There is some data that was written to the Analytics database due to this.

Now we are looking to get rid of this data and start fresh. We want to go the route of truncating the data out of the tables. Is there a way to do this? I know this could be done with a built-in functionality for the OMS but not the DMS. Also, what tables would be safe to truncate.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would start fresh by attaching an empty DMS database. You will need to redeploy any goals, page events, campaigns, etc., but it's a much safer option than truncating the tables.

Another thing to consider is that most (if not all) of the reports in the DMS are setup to accept a start and end date. Simply running your reports starting from the launch date may be all you need.

If you decide to truncate the tables, I would focus on any tables that have a Foreign Key relationship to the Visits table (the DMS ships with a Database Diagram that's really handy for stuff like this). Going in order that would be the `PageEvents`, `Pages`, and `Profiles` tables. Then it should be safe to clear out the `Visits` table.